# class loader: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/aaa/.m2/repository/com/st/module-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/st/resource (No such file or directory)

Tags: java

I have problems with class loaders.
Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't work.

When I started, I have tested this works but not from `*.jar`:

```
URL url = AcAnalyzer.class.getResource("../stuff/resource");

// and this works even from jar file:
URL url = Acnalyzer.class.getResource("/stuff/resource");
URL url = AcAnalyzer.class.getClassLoader().getResource("stuff/resource");

// But I got into the problem with tomcat..when I need to deploy it into the tomcat I had to do this:
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("something.xml");
```

where `something.xml` has to be in WEB-INF/classes/

... `url.getFile();`

The problem is that most of the time it has to work within and not within jar at the same time. Now I have test where my class is getting resource, and the jar file is used in some project deployed under the tomcat.. and somehow it doesn't want to work anymore:

I'm bit puzzled about class loaders. How to get this resource? And and the same time have working test.

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("com/st/resource");
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(url.getFile());
```

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/aaa/.m2/repository/com/st/module-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/st/resource (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the question is in the first part, although I'd advise not using "../" in a resource path.

For the second part, if you want to load a resource you shouldn't use FileInputStream - you should use `getResourceAsStream()` instead of `getResource().getFile()`. Just load from that `InputStream` - there won't always be an individual file that you *can* load with `FileInputStream`.

EDIT: The two ways of referring to a resource are `ClassLoader.getResource` and `Class.getResource` (and the equivalents with the `AsStream` suffix).  The difference between them (the only difference that I'm aware of, although there may be others) is that `Class.getResource` treats the given path as being relative to the package of the class that you call it on. So

```
ClassLoader.getResource("foo/bar/baz/test.xml")
```

is equivalent to

```
foo.bar.SomeClass.class.getResource("baz/test.xml");
```

As for the difference between `Class.getClassLoader()` and  `Thread.getContextClassLoader()` I won't claim to have a good understanding - I suggest you ask that as a separate question.

Comment: the right question should probably be what is the difference bettween all those ways of getting a class loader and getting the resource.

Comment: thank you. you were right, even though I don't fully understand why it works with getResourceAsStream() and not with getResource().getFile().

Comment: @michal2: Because when it's a resource embedded in a jar file there *isn't* a file that you can open directly.